# Moment.js Date parse exception in java

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I am using  this format to getting a date from a user on a form

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

getting this

```
// May 30th 2018, 11:38:58 am
```

but when try to format this date in java  like below  getting a parse exception

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
            Date date= ft.parse(jsonObject.get("date").getAsString());
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong , any working example

Comment: `MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a` vs `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a` - can you honestly not see the difference ... in the position of the `,`

Comment: You have comma in wrong place, after dd in java and after year in js

Comment: @JaromandaX yes u right but after replacing  MMM dd yyyy, h:mm:ss a still getting the same error

Comment: @jcubic I use this  MMM dd yyyy, h:mm:ss a but still getting  the same error

Comment: well ... `MMMM` =  for example `January`, `MMM` is `Jan` ... `Do` = for example `30th`, `dd` = `30` .... etc ... for hours = 3, `hh` = `03` but `h` = `3` .... I mean the two formats are almost unrelated

Comment: @JaromandaX can u elaborate with some example

Comment: I just did!!! personally, I'd use ISO 8601 format and be done with it

Comment: Let me ask this ... your javascript is sending `May 30th 2018, 11:38:58 am` and you're trying to parse this using `MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss a` ?

Comment: change `moment().format('MMM DD YYYY, hh:mm:ss a');` in javascript ... then try using `MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss a` in java

Comment: @JaromandaX wonderful

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `th` , it is not mandatory

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);

        String dateString = "May 30th 2018, 11:38:58 am";
        Date date= ft.parse(dateString
                .replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(st|nd|rd|th)", "")
        );
```